# Using .NET Core social auth (AddAuthentication) for web and mobile app

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth

I have a website that lets users login using a few external OAuth providers, like Facebook and Google. I've essentially followed the steps here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

When the users are logged in, they can access a list of items they've added, which are stored in the database.

If I wanted to allow an app (using React Native) to let users login with the same credentials, what steps should I take? Right now I can log in to my app using Google, but I'm not sure the proper way to validate the user logging in on the app is the same as the user in the website.

Another thing I need to look into is how to let a user to sign up using the app as well. Right now on the website using AddAuthentication, the user is asked to enter their email address. How should I go about implementing this in the app?

Answer (score 0):

> > If I wanted to allow an app (using React Native) to let users login with the same credentials, what steps should I take

You can use [react-native-oauth](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth) which is a react-native wrapper for social authentication login for both Android and iOS , supports identity providers like Google,Facebook,Twitter...

> > , but I'm not sure the proper way to validate the user logging in on the app is the same as the user in the website.

Not sure what do you mean by "validate " . Login with external identity provider , for example , Google, you can use Google account to login in your website application or mobile application , the accounts are managed by identity provider(Google) , so that's the same user.

> > Another thing I need to look into is how to let a user to sign up using the app as well.

Since users are managed by each identity provider , you need to redirect user to identity provider's account sign up page , or you can call APIs if identity providers provide APIs for user sign up .